# Setting real path to MockServletContext

Tags: java, spring, servlets, junit

I am trying to stub `MockServletConfig` and `MockServletContext`. In my servlet `init()` method servlet gets the realPath like this:

```
String realPath = servletContext.getRealPath(fileSeperator+"WEB-INF");
```

For my test case realPath is coming as null. I am trying to set it up like this:

```
MockServletContext context = new MockServletContext();
        context.setContextPath("D:/Projects/ProjectName/webapps");
        MockServletConfig config = new MockServletConfig(context);
```

Here WEB-INF folder is in `webapps` folder.

What is wrong with my `MockServletContext`?

Answer (score 0):

As of Spring 3.x `getRealPath` is based on `resourceBasePath` and not `contextPath`, so just set it correctly using appropriate constructor of `MockServletContext`

```
new MockServletContext("D:/Projects/ProjectName/webapps", null)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `file:/` before your path.
For example:

```
ServletContext context = new MockServletContext("file:/D:/Projects/ProjectName/webapps");
```